# How can I convert HTML characters to their equivalents on the iPhone?

Tags: html, xml, iphone

I want to convert:

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
  &lt;Company&gt;
    &lt;CompanyId&gt;5&lt;/CompanyId&gt;
    &lt;Name&gt;Acme Inc.&lt;/Name&gt;
  &lt;/Company&gt;
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Company>
    <CompanyId>5</CompanyId>
    <Name>Acme Inc.</Name>
  </Company>
```

on a iPhone. But I can't find any standard functions available on the iPhone, nor could I find any mature (open source) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Will [CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFXMLTreeRef/Reference/reference.html) work for you?

Comment: Partly, since this requires some manual coding of the character equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities works OK on the simulator but not on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Grab MWFeedParser from GitHub, one of the files will convert everything for you

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

look at this functions

- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;

...this should at least lead you in the right direction